# How could this creature clothe itself?

Tags: fantasy-races, clothing

The creature's body is mostly like a sea lion, with a few strange features: The head and neck are not in the usual place, but instead is in the middle of the back. The head is human-like, and the neck is long and flexible. The front of the chest, where the head and neck usually are, is covered in smooth flesh. It also has a long tail. They live primarily in the ocean, but can come onto land to get materials or buy clothes from humans

The creatures wish to cover their teats, the front of their chest, and their excretory/reproductive organs (all of which are in their normal places) in a way that works above and below the water. How could they do this in a comfortable way?

[image: A picture of the creature]

Here is a drawing of the creature without clothing

Comment: It's to decide how to cover something that you don't say where it is located...

Comment: Poncho seems to be the easiest solution. Floating of suspended in the water the creature would swim head first into it draping the garment over their body legs. Finalize by using their mouth to reposition it as suited them.

Comment: I see the "hands" and "feet" may not be dexterous enough to facilitate the creature to dress itself. I think we need a little bit more information about the movements. For example: Can the creature somehow reach the head with his hands? How close can the mouth get to the body? (That is neccesary to understand what kind of clothes could the creature put itself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Lycra / Spandex swimsuit.

These are a real thing and can be made to whatever animal form you want. The closest I can find to your picture is a horse, but shouldn't be a problem to someone with a sewing machine and a few bolts of spandex.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can  I ask why you would coat a horse in spandex?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Apparently there are multiple reasons. Thermal reasons, but also to keep the horse clean and as a protective layer of clothing. It's a step up from the protective sheets that are more common. "sleazy lycra sheet" produces hundreds of results. Sometimes it's even used as sleepwear.

Answer (score 2):

Use a poncho, with extra buttons on the bottom.

Or a sack, with four holes - five counting the tail - and a very wide mouth; the mouth can be closed by pulling a string, all around the neck.

The poncho would probably work better when *exiting* the water, as the soaked cloth would otherwise drag underneath.